# Open link either in existing iframe or run code, depending on if iframe exists

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm green to javascript, but I have some C++ in my background, so I understand the principles of coding, just don't do much web stuff. 
I have an e-mail link that needs to do one of two things depending upon whether an iframe exists. This code exists in the parent page (index.html), so the iframe would be a child (I presume). 
If there is no iframe yet, I need this code (gb_page_fs[] calls some code to create the iframe).

```
<a href="contact.html" rel="gb_page_fs[]">e-mail</a>
```

If the iframe exists it would be named "GB_frame" and this is the code I would need for the link:

```
<a href="contact.html" target="GB_frame">e-mail</a>
```

I have two issues: Trying to identify if the frame exists and executing the second case code. I've seen a lot of code to identify parent iFrame names, but not child. The closest I've gotten with that is document.getElementById("framename").name, but I'm getting "Cannot read property 'name' of null". As for the latter, I'm guessing there is a simple solution, but I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track testing for the iframe. You want to do something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('framename');
// if the iframe doesn't exist x will be null and the if statement evaluates to false
if(x) 
{
  doSomething();
}
```

To set the source of the iframe:

```
    document.getElementById('framename').src = 'url to page';
```

Comment: Geoff, thanks! That gets me one step closer. However, I am getting the same result whether or not the frame is open. Does it matter that the iframe is created & loaded dynamically? I'm temporarily running this as a function called thru a form button with an alert output to show me if it's following the "if" logic or the "else" logic.
    function checkframe() {                
      var x=document.getElementById('GB_frame');
      if (x)
        {alert(x.value +" if");}
      else
        {alert("else ");}
    }

Comment: @thirdstring No, it doesn't matter when the iframe is added (as long as it's there before you look for it). I noticed you have x.value in your alert. Value is not a valid attribute of an iframe so you will get an undefined.  Take a look at this link: [http://jsfiddle.net/vEnjR/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/vEnjR/3/). It's a working example of dynamically adding an iframe and then verifying it exists. Let me know if you have more questions.